# DOM form value manipulation

Tags: javascript, php, dom

i have a little question, lets say i have three radio buttons in my form to select one of three images.

```
<input type="radio" value="1.jpg" />
<input type="radio" value="2.jpg" />
<input type="radio" value="3.jpg" />
```

before i submit the form i manipulate the DOM and set the value of the first radio to 10 how can i handle this issue?

For sure i can check with php if the 20.jpg exists, but are there any other solutions?

Thanks for helping

Comment: So what is exactly your question? Do you want to know how to set the value of the first radio to `10` or do you want to check if the value of selected radio is not `20.jpg`?

Comment: set name attribute in your radio button. In the server side keep an array of possible values(e.g 1,2,3). When data posted to the server check if incoming values within your array or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want to make sure a user can't change the value submitted via the form; i.e. you want to ensure the value is either `1.jpg`, `2.jpg`, or `3.jpg`. Assuming that's correct:

You need to add a `name` attribute to your radios, as @AwaidLiton says, so that PHP can pick up the value via the `$_POST` variable (which is populated with data from the form):

```
<input name="image" type="radio" value="1.jpg" />
<input name="image" type="radio" value="2.jpg" />
<input name="image" type="radio" value="3.jpg" />
```

You need to validate this at least on the server-side, i.e. with PHP. Something like this (assuming your form uses `method="POST"`:

```
// Check if image submitted
if (!empty($_POST['image']) {
    $valid_values = array('1.jpg', '2,jpg', '3.jpg');
    if (in_array($_POST['image'], $valid_values) {
        // Value is valid, continue doing whatever
    } else {
        // Value is invalid, notify user/show error message
    }
}
```

This is obviously a very simple example, but you get the idea.

You can also validate client side using JavaScript. You may wish to use a library to do so, or modify your question to ask for help with that.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to accept values within your possible expectation values then you will need to store it in the server side.  When form data is posted in the server you can check if incoming value is within possible values or not.

```
<input name="myInput" type="radio" value="1.jpg" />
<input name="myInput" type="radio" value="2.jpg" />
<input name="myInput" type="radio" value="3.jpg" />
```

Sever side PHP:

```
$arr_values = ["1.jpg", "2.jpg", "3.jpg"] 
if isset($_REQUEST["myInput"]) && in_array($_REQUEST["myInput"], $arr_values)  {

// Do your stuff (values within array)
}
else {

// invalid value
}
```